# Version Routing in Web Api and versioned controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using .Net 4.5.2

Am using versioned routing in Web Api.

The spec requires that we define the following routes:

/api/v1/members/test

/api/v2/members/test

The following code finds the correct methods in version 1.

```
 private static IEnumerable<VersionedRoute> GetRoutes(int version)
    {
        var routes = new List<VersionedRoute>();
        if (version >= 1)
        {
            var versionedRoutes = new List<VersionedRoute>
            {
                new VersionedRoute(
                    version,
                    "Test",
                    "/Members/{id}/{action}",
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"controller", "Members"},
                        {"action", "Test"},
                        {"id", RouteParameter.Optional}
                    })
            };

            routes.AddRange(versionedRoutes);
        }

        if (version >= 2)
        {
            var versionedRoutes = new List<VersionedRoute>{
                new VersionedRoute(
                    version,
                    "TestV2",
                    "/Members/{id}/{action}",
                    new RouteValueDictionary
                    {
                        {"controller", "MembersV2"},
                        {"action", "Test"},
                        {"id", RouteParameter.Optional}
                    }),
            };
            routes.AddRange(versionedRoutes);
        }

        return routes;
    }
```

For v1 this all works when we define our methods as follows

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Test")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetTest(string id)
        {
            var x = "GET: Well helleeoo";
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted) {Content =  new StringContent(x)};
        }

        [HttpPut]
        [ActionName("Test")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutTest(string id)
        {
            var x = "PUT: Well helleeoo";
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted) { Content = new StringContent(x) };
        }
```

However, as you can see for the v2 route I want to direct the request to a different controller (MembersV2) where it will find the v2 methods but keep the same route exposed. Unfortunately, MembersV2 does not get found so when I send a request to api/v2/members/test, although the route is found, the Members controller is called and the old v1 methods are executed.

Is there something I am not understanding here.  Can anyone help?

Please ask for more clarification if I am not being clear?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple way of doing API Versioning. You definitely do not want to reinvent the wheel, because it could be very complex.

You can read [ASP.NET Web API: Using Namespaces to Version Web APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/).

In [ASP.NET Web API 2: Building a REST Service from Start to Finish](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484201108) book Page 57, Jamie Kurtz explains how he modified above code to suit his needs in new Web API 2.

I personally like Jamie Kurtz's modified version, and use it in few of my APIs.

Comment: this is the way it has been done in the app so other methods are currently not on the table

Comment: Gee it would have been handy to see Jamie's modified version, though I appreciate the book is copyright.

Comment: Ditto @JeremyThompson -- I realize even the Skeeter says [link-only can be okay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers#comment15230_8259), but link to book is yet another remove. Fair use in the US at the very least should allow a good sum and demo of the advice here to make this a useful answer. As is, not so much. (Btw, I don't see it on [this version on page 57](https://books.google.com/books?id=e5Y5xymk15cC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ASP.NET+Web+API+2:+Building+a+REST+Service+from+Start+to+Finish&hl=en#v=onepage&q=57).)

Answer (score 0):

Your route defined in both cases is `"/Members/{id}/{action}"` so the request to `v2/members/test` matches the template of the first v1 route (as the order of the route definitions matter when matching requests)

So what you need to do is define your routes with explicit versions like so:

```
private static IEnumerable<VersionedRoute> GetRoutes(int version)
{
    var routes = new List<VersionedRoute>();
    if (version >= 1)
    {
        var versionedRoutes = new List<VersionedRoute>
        {
            new VersionedRoute(
                version,
                "Test",
                "v1/Members/{id}/{action}",
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"controller", "Members"},
                    {"action", "Test"}
                })
        };

        routes.AddRange(versionedRoutes);
    }

    if (version >= 2)
    {
        var versionedRoutes = new List<VersionedRoute>{
            new VersionedRoute(
                version,
                "TestV2",
                "v2/Members/{id}/{action}",
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"controller", "MembersV2"},
                    {"action", "Test"}
                }),
        };
        routes.AddRange(versionedRoutes);
    }

    return routes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry the route should be api/v2/members/test

Comment: I updated my answer but the same reason still applies

Comment: I dont really get what you are trying to do.  Id in this scenario is used for something else, not for versioning]